# how to get the number of periods used by pd.corr()

Tags: pandas, correlation

How can I figure out the *quality* of a correlation obtained with [`pd.corr()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html?highlight=corr#pandas.DataFrame.corr)?

And by quality, I mean how much of the data is overlapping and thus used by `.corr()`. Let's illustrate this with a short example:

Lets set up a sample dataframe:

```
time1 = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-01-5', freq='D')
time2 = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-04', end='2020-01-8', freq='D')
time3 = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-01-8', freq='D')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(time1)), index=time1, columns=['first'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(time2)), index=time2, columns=['second'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(time3)), index=time3, columns=['third'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(time3)), index=time3, columns=['forth'])
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4], axis=1)
```

AS you can see, `first` and `second` share only two data points, whereas `third` and `forth` have data for the whole period, and thus share all of that between them, and 5 data points with `first` and `second` respectively.

Or in a graphic:

[image]

Obviously, it'll be different each time, because of `np.random.randn`, but in this special case, it nicely illustrates my point. If we look at the correlation matrix, `df.corr()`

```
           first    second     third     forth
first   1.000000  1.000000  0.034076 -0.023059
second  1.000000  1.000000 -0.021810  0.928713
third   0.034076 -0.021810  1.000000  0.458744
forth  -0.023059  0.928713  0.458744  1.000000
```

We not only see the expected perfect correlation of the diagonal, but apparently, `first` and `second` also have a perfect correlation (same gradient in the plot). Now, mathematically, this seems to be true, however, assuming all three columns observe the same kind of phenomena, I would call the correlations for the others, especially `third` and `forth` better, since I have much more data available.

Whether `first` and `second` really have a better correlation than the others will show when I have the same amount of data.

Now with such a simple dataframe, it's quite trivial to obtain this information, but let's assume a dataframe with a few hundred entries and times starting in the 1930s and this simple visual identification becomes tedious, if not impossible.

**How do I get the information of the overlaps of the correlation matrix in a straightforward and simple way?**

`pd.corr()` has the option `min_periods`, so I could set this to `min_periods = 3` to discard the low overlap correlation in this example, but real data, I'd rather not exclude anything, but simply have information about the number of periods that were used to obtain the correlation.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet found a quick and easy way to get the numbers, but for my application, a quick visual overview also works.

With the test data above, this is not really needed, but lets keep using it for illustrative purposes.

A simple `plt.imshow(df, aspect='auto')` works quite good. But since I'm just interested in data vs. no data (so, any number vs. NaN) multiplying it with zero works better (NaN gets left as is and is painted white by `imshow`, any number becomes zero and thus gets a color. So:

```
plt.imshow((df*0), aspect='auto')
```

[image]

Or with some real data:

[image]

Not perfect (so I'm not going to accept this answer), but a good first step to identify which data are good and which are less so.